# Assets on nitrous.io are not loading even though html is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nitrousio

I am currently developing a website on nitrous and i have some problems.

my html code loads as a home page but there was no images, there were only images of "file not found"

[image: file not found]

the html was in folder "static_pages", ie. `static_pages/home.html.erb`
while the images are in the same folder. ie. `static_pages/images`

when i ran rails s and tried to see the web, the images does not load.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the image by naked filename (in a view), Rails will retrieve them from `app/assets/images/` by default.
You mentioned this is a static page, so I assume you are referencing the images with a path.
That path would be *assumed* to be from `app/public/`.

If you create a subdirectory `app/public/static_images/` you can reference the images in your static HTML page as `static_images/filename`.